# Disabling the incremental project builder while using LSP

Tags: xtext, xtend, language-server-protocol

I am using the xtext `LanguageServer` in my project and currently the LSP is configured to inrementalBuild which calls the `GeneratorDelegate` within the `IncrementalBuilder` class. Is there any way to disable the incrementalBuild ?

to tackle this I used the following approach by extending the IncrementalBuilder class and commenting out the GeneratorDelegate.

```
protected void generate(Resource resource, BuildRequest request, Source2GeneratedMapping newMappings) {
            IResourceServiceProvider serviceProvider = getResourceServiceProvider(resource);
            Set<URI> previous = newMappings.deleteSource(resource.getURI());
            URIBasedFileSystemAccess fileSystemAccess = createFileSystemAccess(serviceProvider, resource);
            fileSystemAccess.setBeforeWrite((uri, outputCfgName, contents) -> {
                newMappings.addSource2Generated(resource.getURI(), uri, outputCfgName);
                previous.remove(uri);
                request.getAfterGenerateFile().apply(resource.getURI(), uri);
                return contents;
            });
            fileSystemAccess.setBeforeDelete((uri) -> {
                newMappings.deleteGenerated(uri);
                request.getAfterDeleteFile().apply(uri);
                return true;
            });
            fileSystemAccess.setContext(resource);
            if (request.isWriteStorageResources()) {
                storeBinaryResource(resource, fileSystemAccess);
            }
            GeneratorContext generatorContext = new GeneratorContext();
            generatorContext.setCancelIndicator(request.getCancelIndicator());
            // un-comment the lines below to start incremental build.
//          GeneratorDelegate generator = serviceProvider.get(GeneratorDelegate.class);
//          generator.generate(resource, fileSystemAccess, generatorContext);
            XtextResourceSet resourceSet = request.getResourceSet();
            for (URI noLongerCreated : previous) {
                try {
                    resourceSet.getURIConverter().delete(noLongerCreated, Collections.emptyMap());
                    request.getAfterDeleteFile().apply(noLongerCreated);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeIOException(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a better approach to disable the IncrementalBuilder?

Comment: you can simply bind a null impl for GeneratorDelegate